# Strange routing in rails render partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and thought I had finally figured out some of this routing stuff, but have been going in circles with this bit all day.

I was following a tutorial about building a twitter like service, and I've got the basics working from the tutorial, but with Mongo instead of mySql.

I've got 3 types of pages. 
The home page which is showing all the posts ordered by date

The user page which is showing the posts from a specific user

The posts page which is showing posts from a users friends.

So for each page, I've done the following

1) created a method in the corresponding controller to get the correct posts

2) created a _posts.html.erb page with the display parameters, which are slightly different on each page

3) referenced the partial in the index.html.erb page for each view.

The controller entries look like this

```
  def index
   @posts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
  end
```

or

```
def posts
  @posts = Post.all(:conditions => {'user_id' => params[:id]}, :order => 'created_at DESC')
    end
```

and the partials are

```
<%= render :partial => @posts %>
```

In each view is a _posts.html.erb file, and each is slightly different

home/_posts.html.erb looks like this

```
<%= div_for post do %>
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago
    Posted By <%= post.user_id %>
    <%= post.text %>
<% end %>
```

while posts/_post.html.erb looks like this

```
<%= div_for post do %>
    Posted By <%= post.user_id %>
    <%= post.text %>
<% if post.created_at > 52.hours.since %>
    <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(post.created_at) %>
        <% else %>
        <%= post.created_at.strftime("%c") %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now the strange part is that on all the pages index.html.erb, users/show.html.erb, posts/index.html.erb, the partial that is being displayed is the posts/_post.html.erb. The others are being completely ignored.

my understanding was that render :partial would take the @posts and render _posts.html.erb from the current view. But this isn't happening, as only the posts/_post.html.erb is being rendered from all views.

I've looked in the routes.rb file, but don't have anything in there that would cause this problem.

Can anybody tell me why I am not displaying the proper partials?

-----------Edited --------------------------------

The directory structure for views is as follows

```
views 
      - home
            -_post.html.erb
            -index.htlm.erb
      - layouts
      - posts
            -_post.html.erb
            -index.html.erb
            -posts.html.erb
      - sessions 
      - users
            -_post.html.erb
            -new.html.erb
            -show.html.erb
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Can you give your views directory structure? It is a bit confusing as to where what is. Does `users/show.html.erb` exist inside `posts` as a sub-directory or outside.

Comment: thanks shripad, i added the directory structure to the question. maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

"post", :collection => @posts%>

maybe rails automatically defines path to the partial when you pass only collection

Comment: Thanks Bohdan, that does work, but the question is why? I shouldn't need to pass in the collection based on my understanding of RoR. Any ideas why it is needed in this instance?

Comment: I suppose that rails automatically defines path to the partial as "/posts/_post.rb" because when you use "form_for @person" rails parse it and the output is "form action="/persons/create" method="post"" But I may be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the collection as the argument that rails is expecting to be the name of the partial. Your call to render should look like this

`<%= render partial: "post", collection: @posts %>`

This will render `app/views/posts/_post.html.erb`, passing the local variable `post` to the partial.

Additionally, (is sometimes handy) there's an iteration object that is made available to this view, `partial_name_iteration`, that has information about the total size of the `@posts` collection, and the index of the current object.